# What's the use of "?!" in this RewriteCond?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, apache2

I frequently see the `?!` combination in `RewriteCond` given in `.htaccess` files, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!/slim_demo/index\.php).*$
```

To my understanding, this directive checks if `/slim_demo/index.php` isn't part of the `REQUEST_URI`. Which is odd; what is the use of the `?` at the very front, especially when it has no preceding character to match. The documentation says that `?` "[makes the match optional](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#regex)", but the only thing preceding the `?` is the grouping bracket. Does it mean that `?` is making grouping optional? Makes so sense!

What is the mystery?

Comment: It's a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: @arco444 Ah, I wish I had known how to search about it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative Lookahead After the Match: \d+(?!\d| dollars)
Sample Match: 100 in 100 pesos
Explanation: \d+ matches 100, then the negative lookahead (?! dollars) asserts that at that position in the string, what immediately follows is neither a digit nor the characters " dollars"